# Passing variables through exit signals [Erlang]

Tags: erlang, exit

I'm wondering if it's possible to send variables from a dying process to it's calling process.  I have a process A that spawned another process B through spawn_link.  B is about to die by calling exit(killed).  I can catch this in A through {'EXIT', From, killed}, but I'd like to pass some variables from B to A before it dies. I can do this by sending a message from B to A right before it dies, but I'm wondering if this is a 'bad' thing to do.  Because technically I'd be sending two messages from B to A.  Right now, what I have looks like this:

```
B sends a message with values to A
A receives values and re-enters receive loop
B calls exit(killed)
A receives EXIT message and spawns another linked process
```

The idea is that B should always exist and when it gets killed, it should be 'resurrected' immediately.  What seems like a better alternative in my opinion is to have something like exit(killed, [Variables]) and to catch it with {'EXIT', From, killed, [Variables]}. Is this possible?  And if so, are there any reasons for not doing it?  Having A store values for B when B hasn't even died yet seems like a bad move. I'd have to start implementing atomic actions to prevent problems with two linked processes dying at the same time.  It also forces me to keep the variables in my receive loop.

What I mean is, if I could send values directly with the EXIT call, my loop would look like this:

```
loop() ->
    receive ->
        {'EXIT', From, killed, Variables} -> % spawn new linked process with variables
    end.
```

But if I first need to receive a message, get into the loop again to then receive the exit message, I would get;

```
loop(Vars) ->
    receive ->
        {values, Variables} -> loop(Variables);
        {'EXIT', From, killed} -> % spawn new linked process with variables
    end.
```

This means I keep the list of variables long after I don't need them anymore and I need to enter my loop twice for what could be considered one action.

Comment: Why not to store them in ets or mnesia table? If you use  ets table as variables container, then you can specify [heir option](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#heir). So you can just pass them around.

Comment: It's nicely explained here: http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2011/03/23/dont-lose-your-ets-tables/

Comment: Don't do that. The crashing process should be always respawned with clean state, because bad state is usually the reason of crash. This can "pollute" rest of the system. If you are sure, that data is always OK, but the processing logic might crash - split it into two processes: one for holding the state and nothing else and other for processing data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly: the exit reason can be *any term*, which means it can also be a tuple like `exit({killed, Values})`, so instead of receiving `{'EXIT', From, killed, Values}` you would received `{'EXIT', From, {killed, Values}}`.

**But!**

The way you are doing it now is not *wrong*. Its not particularly ugly, either. Sending a message (especially an asynchronous one) isn't some major operation to be minimized as much as possible, and neither is spawning/killing processes. If your way works for you, fine.

**But! (again!)**

Why are you doing this in the first place? Consider what it is about state that you need to be shuttling between two processes, one of which you are terminating just then? Should this value be a permanent entity held by the spawning process? Should it die with the worker? Should it be a quantity maintained by a third process and asked for as part of the worker's startup (a more general phrasing of what Łukasz Ptaszyński was getting at)?

I don't know the answers to those questions, because I don't know your program, but they are the things I would think about if I was finding it necessary to do this sort of work. In particular, if there is some base value that process A must seed process B with for it to work, and the next version of the base value is dependent on something process B does, then *process B should be returning it as a part of its processing*, not as a part of its shutdown.

This seems like a minor semantic difference, but its important to think about. You may find that you shouldn't be terminating B at all, or that you really need A to manage a directory for several concurrent B's and they should seed themselves as they move along, or whatever. You might even find that this means A should be spawning B as a synchronous, monitored operation, not an asynchronous linked one, and the whole herd of processes should be spawned as a complex of multiple managed A-B pairs! I don't know the answers in your case, but these are the things that come to mind on reading what you are doing.

Comment: Very nicely explained, just as with my previous question. :) Process B has some variables that change over time. I'm testing around how to deal with situations where processes die frequently. A technically shouldn't know anything about the variables of B, but if B dies, A should recreate a new process B' that gets the values B had.  To do this, A needs to briefly get a hold of the variables of B, but not anymore once B' has been created to replace B. The ets table suggested by Lukasz is definitely interesting; I did not know of this.

Comment: @Babyburger You may want either a process to act as a value registry (a value logger so you can pick up where you left off), or an `exit({died, Value})`. But why are your workers dying so often? If these are crashes (not terminations), how would they send values back? How do you guarantee that something about the value isn't what crashes them (passing the same data back into a respawn/suicide cycle)? There are answers to these, but they depend on context so only you can find them. My point is to think carefully about the essence of the problem, not the artifact of the proposed solution.

Comment: @Babyburger Maybe we can avoid that too? Let's assume we are using main supervisor with strategy rest_for_one which supervises "supervisor of process B" and "process A" (order matters here) both permanent. So when "process B" crashes to much (because of corrupted data) its supervisor crashes too and main supervisor will also restart "process A". Corrupted data will be lost and "process A" can start with new data or use some backup maybe? Yea... Too much thinking about failing ;) Maybe i just exaggerate but point is to take advantage of supervisors hierarchy and heal by expanding crushes.

Comment: I have a similar situation and was wondering if sending values over an exit value would be a good choice? I have a homework on understanding failure in Erlang. We have to make the game 2048, where every tile on the field is a process that propagates values according to the command (up,down,left,right) and our professor added a blaster that would randomly kill some of the tiles by sending it a message to die making it exit itself. An easy way would be the exit statement, but would there be a cleaner way to send information between the board-monitor and the tiles after they exited?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I've got a similar situation in a different game. In mine, the way an element dies dictates how long it should take to respawn, but a *crash* requires immediate resurrection. In this case I send a message to the supervisor `{LocID, blasted, RestartDelay}` and then `exit(normal)` (or don't loop, which is the same). In an error situation (like an exiting mob fails to be removed from the loc inventory) the loc kills itself `exit({error, inv})`, and any other case it will just be restarted because the crash was deliberate. Use messages for notification; treat crashes as crashes.

Comment: @zxq9 But what if the element crashes before it can send a message that it is about to crash? Is there a way to recover from that? Or should the element periodically update its value to a central storage?

Comment: @PeterRaeves If it dies before its message is sent, the supervisor restarts it; it was a crash, we don't want a delay. If it dies in the tiny gap between the "bullet" and its proper death message, you have a (very rare) system error; a *transient bug* that won't occur again. That's OK in most cases (a user will just click "blow tile!" again, thinking they missed). You can also make the "bullet" message synchronous: `receive {From, Ref, boom} -> Boss ! {LocID, blasted, RestartDelay}, From ! {Ref, ok}, exit(normal) end` so now the sender knows something is wrong if the synch timeout is hit.

Comment: Thinking about it another way, if your process dies in the tiny gap between receiving a "bullet" message and sending its proper death message, you are at least recovering instantly to a known state. This is *true* failure, and the system is handling it without totally collapsing. Consider how this works in any other environment: a crash within an object in a Java program is *just* as likely, but would *take down the entire game*. You can't handle every *failure* as part of the *intended* system (what if the top supervisor, or the runtime crash?), but you can recover to a known state from most.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this method:

```
main()->
    ParentPid = self(),
    From = spawn_link(?MODULE, child, [ParentPid]),
    receive
    {'EXIT', From, Reason} ->
        Reason
    end.



child(ParentPid) ->
    Value = 2*2,
    exit(ParentPid, {killed, Value}).
```

Please read this link about [erlang:exit/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-2)

Comment: There are no persistent processes here. If there were (if Child were a loop) and Parent is trapping exits nothing is being killed by the call to `exit/2`, only an `{'EXIT', Pid, Reason}` message with no side effect. If Parent is not trapping exits (in your example above it is not) *Parent* will be killed by `exit/2`, which is not what the OP is looking for.